# Getting model value in angular directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, bootstrap-datetimepicker

I wrote an angular directive for http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker, and I'm able to have actions on the datetimepicker update my model, but I'm running into problems when I'm trying to set the defaultDate on the datetimepicker control with the value from my model during instantiation.

Here's a plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/XUQSx7s0Fle2Xes77VrM?p=preview

**script.js**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('DemoCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.modelDate = new Date("01/01/2010");
});

app.directive('datetimepicker', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
      // scope.$apply(); //This fixes the issue, but throws error in console
      element.datetimepicker( {
        defaultDate: ngModelCtrl.$modelValue
      })
      .on('dp.change', function(e) {
        ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(e.date);
        scope.$apply();
      });
    }
  };
});
```

**Relevant portion of index.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
    <div class="input-group date" datetimepicker ng-model="modelDate">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
    Date from model: {{modelDate}}
  </div>
</div>
```

It looks like the problem is at the time datetimepicker gets instantiated, the model is null. Doing `scope.$apply()` before instantiating the datetimepicker solves this problem, but throws an error in the console, and this doesn't feel like the right way to go about it. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forcing an $apply call on our scope isn't the wisest thing to do.
Perhaps you should try deferring it to the next digest cycle?

Using a utility library (like [Underscorejs](http://underscorejs.org/)), try the following:

```
_.defer(function(){scope.$apply();});
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I moved the entire body of the `link` function into `defer`, and it seems to be working without the need for `scope.$apply();` Is this the best way to go about this?

Comment: Well, you want to make sure the `datepicker` element has been initialized on the DOM before you place an event handler on it. Not sure if this is the best way to go about it, but it's a feasible solution that doesn't anger the AngularJS gods! (See [Anti-Patterns](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/wiki/Anti-Patterns))